# Not able to set setImageResource for ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I am trying to set the **`ImageButtom.setImageResource()`** **without being clicked**.

When **using `onClickListener`** it is **working**.

Something like this :

```
Key.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
          ((ImageButton)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);  

        }
    });
```

**However**, when I try to change the `ImageResource` **without being click** something like this:

```
key.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
```

it is **not working**. And I don't know why???

In my code, there is **`conditional statement`** where I want to **change** the **`ImageResource`** according to the **condition** where it is **fit** but I am not able to do it.

**Does anyone know how to change it without being clicked???**

here is my complete code for `public View getView` GRIDVIEW:

```
 name = v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    itemImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.Image);
    Key = v.findViewById(R.id.LikeKey);

    name.setText(data.getITEM_NAME());
    Glide.with(context).load(data.getITEM_IMAGE()).into(itemImageView);

    itemImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You have selected " + 
  data.getITEM_NAME(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, 
   Detail.class).putExtra("activity", "foodlist")
                    .putExtra("type", data.getTREE()));
        }
    });

    final ValueEventListener eventListener= new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if 
        (dataList.get(position).getITEM_KEY().equals(ds.getKey())) {
                        
       reference.child(dataList.get(position).getITEM_KEY()).removeValue();
                        if (map.size()!=0){
                            map.clear();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        
        reference.updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                   
     //Since this line is not working 
     //Key.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart))
    //I use this instead
   ((ImageButton)click).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            }else{
                reference.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            ((ImageButton)click).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };

    final String key= data.getITEM_KEY();
    final String name= data.getITEM_NAME();

    Key.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            click=v;
            map.put(key,name);
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        }
    });

   
//Checking availability
    {
  
    reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()){

                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){

                    if (dataList.get(position).getITEM_KEY().equals(ds.getKey())) {
                 //this line is not working
                        Key.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    }
```

The **XML** code:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/LikeKey"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_heart2" />
```

Comment: make sure `key` is not null

Comment: Key is not null it's already define. I am using it in GridView.

Comment: It's is working fine when using the method `.setImageResource` under ClickListener like the way I have mentioned above. However, while using under conditions like example there more than 5 value stored at Variable `C` now there I want to change it. I tried using like I have mentioned `Key.setImageResource(MyDrawableFile)` which is not accepting the change

Comment: It's like something is missing there which I don't know!!

Comment: if you call `Key.setImageRes(...)` right where you set the onClickListener, does this work? i mean in the same method (i guess onCreate)

Comment: Have you tried saving the `V` from `public void onClick(View v)` to new `View` variable and using it on the conditions???

Comment: @olidem nope, it doesn't work. It only work when under the `onClick` also if I write the code like this `((ImageButton)v).setImageResource(MyDrawable)` else it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wade if the `Key` is not click I won't be able to save it because I will get null return from `v` if I try to use it

Comment: ok, i still guess the key variable is not refferring to your button properly. try just to change the button’s caption with `setTitle` or similar

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Just saying that `setImageResource()` doesn't work is not nearly enough information to determine why your particular setup isn't working as you expect.

Comment: @MikeM. I have added my complete code please have a look into it. I am not able to figure it out why I am facing the issue.

Comment: @AthosTokbi I see that `click` is a `View` type variable and you used it in the `EventListener` to change it since you said that `Key.setImageResource(Drawable)` is not working. You are using it in **GridView** right?

Comment: @Wade Yes I am using it in GridView

Comment: Is there a way to get  `v` from the `onClick(View v)` without being click so that I will be able to use to change the `ImageButton` **SRC** ????

Answer (score 1):

This is simply confusing. Reduce it to simplest part which should be working. Are you sure that code is reachable inside the if statement where you have this Key.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart); ?

If everything is same it should be working. However it is not working.
Key = v.findViewById(R.id.LikeKey);
((ImageButton)click).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);

Is Key like click ImageButton with appropriate width height and contentType to fit the ImageResource ic_heart?

Comment: Yeah, that what it's the same. But the code doesn't work. I feel something is missing? and I am not able to figure it out. Maybe it's the simplest thing that I am overlooking.

Comment: I recommend to test Key variable. Write this code: Key.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart); somewhere where it will be executed. Put the debugger breakpoints and check various parameters of Key

Comment: I have check it is initializing without any error, but the effect of the code execution doesn't happen. I mean it doesn't make any changes is same as it is. The `onClick` part is working and even changing but my issue is at the part where I have mentioned using comment that `//this line is not working` that part is not showing the code effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally **figured it out** its not a **fix** for the issue but kind of **workaround**

`Key` which I have initialized  `Key = v.findViewById(R.id.LikeKey);`, I have reinitialized the `ImageButton` on the place where it was not working with a different name, then finally the method `.setImageResource` started working. I don't know why, but it seems from my code above the `Key` is not referencing to it or somehow it was returning null when I run the code I didn't find any error like null exception point or something.

However, the issue is fixed. But in case if any of you have a resolution for this I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: It is not a Good way to code to reinitialised the same Variable.